# Hyperledger fabric local and docker versions out of sync

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run the build your first network example. When i go ./byfn.sh generate it works. But when I do ./byfn.sh up it gives me a warning:

```
Local fabric binaries and docker images are out of  sync. This may cause problems.
```

and an error:

```
got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining.
```

Above the warning the versions are written:

```
LOCAL_VERSION=1.3.0

DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.3.0-rc1
```

But I downloaded the fabric using the command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.3.0-rc1
```

(the full link is since I can't post bit.ly links)
which should have installed 1.3.0-rc1 as local version.
Anybody knows why is my local version showing as 1.3.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check the **docker-compose.yaml** the services maybe are pointing to the **1.3.0-rc1** in the services maybe you can point to the **1.3.0** just set the **image** section in each service.

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$ARCH-1.3.0
```

This is an example for the orderer service, you should do it for all.